# generator of a cone

Tags: geometry

[image]

hi I was having trouble understanding what is the midpoint that is being referenced in the book(Precalculus mathematics in a nutshell by professor George F Simmons)
the book states that the lateral area equals the length of this generator multiplied by the distance travelled by its midpoint $$S.2\pi(\frac{1}{2}r)=\pi rs$$

Comment: The midpoint of the segment denoted by the letter $s$.

Comment: but the statement the lateral area equals the length of this  generator multiplied by the distance travelled by its midpoint doesn't equate to  $\pi rs$

Comment: The distance travelled by the midpoint is shown by the dashed smaller circle in the middle of the cone on Fig 30. It has circumference $\pi r$. The length of the generator is $s$.

Comment: My point is that the statement $S*\frac{1}{2}S$ doesn't equate to $\pi rs$ I dont understand the meaning of that statement

Comment: I don't know where you got $s\cdot \frac12s$ from. It says length of generator ($s$) multiplied by the distance travelled by its midpoint ($\pi r$).